# MongoDB 3.0.0/2/3 Java Driver Kerberos Authentication on Windows using JDK1.6.45

Tags: java, mongodb, kerberos, mongodb-java, java-6

My Mongo server should be set up correctly since I can query against it using GSSAPI mechanism with client.

According to the documentation, Java Driver's Kerberos Authentication can be as simple as
    `credentialList.add(MongoCredential.createGSSAPICredential("people/myhost.com@EXAMPLE.COM"));`

The principal I used

1. I tested with Mongo's enterprise version of client and it works: authenticated against Mongo server with Kerberos and can find() against it. (database test, principal "people/myhost.com@EXAMPLE.COM")
2. kinit performed and the new ticket is showed in the klist, ticket cached stored under KRB5CCNAME=D:\Kerberos\tickets.txt (environment variable set)

To make sure krb5.ini/conf is read, I manually set the system property java.security.krb5.conf=C:/Windows/krb5.conf

Before I set the property `javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly`, `GSSAPIAuthenticator.createSaslClient()` catched exception of `GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)`.

After I set the property `javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly=false`, `InternalStreamConnection.open()` catched throwable: `java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to locate a login configuration`

I am really confused here. I thought it is using the ticket cache which is specified under KRB5CCNAME. If I use jaas configuration, what name should I assign it to be?

```
Name {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
   useKeyTab=true
   keyTab="D:\\Kerberos\\people.keytab"
   useTicketCache=false;
};
```

I set it with a random name and it started complaining `GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Attempt to obtain new INITIATE credentials failed! (null))`.

Can you guys help me on this? What else I can try here or are there more useful and detailed logs that I can enable in this case?

Answer (score 1):

Security error messages are cryptic, by design :-/

But there is a nice "[security trace flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/troubleshooting-security.html)" property to help you debug GSSAPI config issues:

```
-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext
```